# Cocos2D sprite constrained to screen

Tags: xcode, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a problem with Cocos2D. I'm trying to have a sprite movable on screen (which I've been able to do), but stop it from being clipped by the edge of the screen.

If I'm correct, sprites are imported to the layer as rectangles (spriteWithFile:@"filename.ext" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, X, Y);).

The only thing I've been able to figure out so far is to setup my code to detect if the rectangle of the sprite has gone outside of the "background" layer, and adjust it accordingly if it does.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly:

```
- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {    

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

    float maxX = winSize.width - selSprite.contentSize.width/2;
    float minX = selSprite.contentSize.width/2;
    float maxY = winSize.height - selSprite.contentSize.height/2;
    float minY = selSprite.contentSize.height/2;

    if (selSprite.position.x > maxX)
    {
        selSprite.position = ccp(maxX, selSprite.position.y);
    }
    else if (selSprite.position.x < minX)
    {
        selSprite.position = ccp(minX, selSprite.position.y);
    }   

    if (selSprite.position.y > maxY)
    {
        selSprite.position = ccp(selSprite.position.x, maxY);
    }
    else if (selSprite.position.y < minY)
    {
        selSprite.position = ccp(selSprite.position.x, minY);
    }

    CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
    selSprite.position = newPos;

}
```

Is there something completely obvious that I'm missing? My sprites keep moving off screen if I drag them, and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
float maxX = winSize.width - selSprite.contentSize.width/2;
float minX = selSprite.contentSize.width/2;
float maxY = ...;
float minY = ...;

if (selSprinte.position.x > maxX)
{
    selSprite.position = ccp(maxX, selSprite.position.y);
}
else if (selSprinte.position.x < minX)
{
    selSprite.position = ccp(minX, selSprite.position.y);
}


if (selSprinte.position.y > maxY)
{
    selSprite.position = ccp(selSprite.position.x, maxY);
}
else if (selSprinte.position.y < minY)
{
    selSprite.position = ccp(selSprite.position.x, minY);
}
```

and add the same code for y.

Comment: I'm getting the error ('CGSize' has no member named 'x') when I build on the first and second line. I added this line at the top of the method (CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;) to allow it to build.  I think the problem is because I haven't defined the contentSize of the sprite in X or Y, would I do that in the same way as the window? (CGSize selSprite = [CCDirector sharedDirector].selSprite;)

Comment: @John: my mystake. CGSize have properties named width and height. I've edited the answer

Comment: That works great, thank you! I did the same thing with the Y coordinates (changed width to height, and X to Y / vice versa) where necessary, but when I move my sprites to the top or bottom of the screen (for the y code), they either lag against the edge, or loop to the other side of the screen. I edited my original code to what I have now.

Comment: @John: i've edited my answer. You should check x and y independently.

Comment: I updated my post to the code that I got to work. The bug was coming from my two last lines being in the else if {} statement, instead of being outside the if loop all together. Thank you so much Andrew!

Answer (score 0):

I have a sprite which is larger in size than the screen size. I used this:

```
node.position = CGPointMake(MIN(MAX(size.width  - node.contentSize.width /2,node.position.x), node.contentSize.width  / 2),
                            MIN(MAX(size.height - node.contentSize.height/2,node.position.y), node.contentSize.height / 2));
```

Using this code, my sprite corner was either outside the screen or at the edge of the screen which helped me to see my complete image by scrolling it.

Here:

```
node = CCSprite
size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]
```